# Problema con ejecución de SQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, revisión-de-código

Quería saber si el siguiente código esta bien, es para filtrar campos utilizando mysql y accediendo con Volley desde Android. Parece ser que no encuentra nada al ejecutar la consulta SQL del PHP, y me temo que algo esta mal seguro. Digamos que la intencion es que la app Android manda la pagina, y desde una pantalla de filtros seleccionables, en este caso para probar solo manda la categoria y se quieren obtener todos los registros de esa categoria. Vale, para que se entienda, quiero mandar dos parámetros desde Android con volley. Uno es número de página y otro categoría​. Lo que quiero es una consulta PHP que reciba esos parámetros y ejecute un SQL con un where con solo el parámetro category y muestre todos lo registros de esa categoría.

```
<?php
//importing Config file
 require_once 'include/Config.php';

    //Getting the page number which is to be displayed  
$page = $_POST['page']; 

//Initially we show the data from 1st row that means the 0th row 
$start = 0; 

//Limit is 2 that means we will show 2 items at once
$limit = 1; 

//Counting the total item available in the database 
$total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id from imageplums "));

//We can go atmost to page number total/limit
$page_limit = $total/$limit; 

//If the page number is more than the limit we cannot show anything 
if($page<=$page_limit){

//Calculating start for every given page number 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

if (isset($_POST['category'])) {

    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $sql = "select * from plums where category='$category' limit $start, $limit";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //Adding results to an array 
 $res = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($res, array(
"name"=>$row['name']));
}
//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode($res);
}else{
        echo "over";
}
}
?>
```

Añado codigo android

```
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServerFilter(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.FILTER_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("category", FiltersActivity.CATEGORY);
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar tambien el codigo de Android?

Comment: Fíjate que estás leyendo `page` de $_GET y `category` de $_POST, comprueba que eso esté bien.

Comment: Saca una traza de la consulta que almacenas en la variable `$sql`, es muy probable que si no tienes habilitado la directiva `magic_quotes` no te esté concatenando el valor y directamente le pase a la base de datos el literal $category. Para evitar esto, envuelve la variable entre los símbolos `{` y `}` o bien concatena los valores de forma explícita.

Comment: Ya he conseguido arreglar la consulta SQL, ya funciona correctamente. Era un error de codigo, La unica pega estaba en pasarle la URL correctamente desde Android.

Comment: Revisa esos SQL injection que tienes, es mala práctica concatenar directamente las variables sin haber escapado de forma correcta los valores. Te podrías sacar la base de datos entera con el código ahí puesto. CUIDADO CON ESO

Comment: podrias cerrar la pregunta?¿ @lopiv2